# Асинхронные операции выполняет ос?

Tags: python, node.js, асинхронность

Я правильно понимаю насчет асинхронности. что все что выполняет асинхронно,  делает ОС? Node, python   обращаются к системе через  Демультиплексор событий или системный вызов? А сами идут выполнять код последовательно, пока ОС выполняет IO read/write сетевые запросы и результат готовый отдает им позже?

Comment: Абсолютно любые сетевые запросы (хоть синхронные, хоть асинхронные) делает ОС, потому что по-другому не бывает. Обращение к системному демультиплексору событий тоже выполняется через системные вызовы.

Comment: Насчет асинхроных запросов io . ОС способна обрабатывать  десятки  тысяч запросов? Параллельно?

Comment: Десятки тысяч это вообще мизерное количество, система [и 12 миллионов вполне потянет](https://migratorydata.com/2013/06/20/12-million-concurrent-connections-with-migratorydata-websocket-server/) если железо позволит